# re pattern to match all n-digit numbers in front of non-digit text

Tags: python, regex

I want to construct a regular expression for this task with Python 3.7.5. The input texts are like following:

```
alkdj flajf
123 adlf ja;ld fj 999
423 234 2359 kalfji lkja;lkd999
```

my goal is retrieve all the numbers in leading positions, a space character after each number, and get a list like following

```
[]
[123]
[423, 234, 2359]
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: you could write  a regex that captures all spaces and digits from the start of the line. then split it by spaces.

Comment: Also online regex sites like https://regex101.com are great places to try out and play with your regex

Comment: As @Chris suggested, you can use `r" ^\d*(?: +\d+)*` to produces the matches `""`, `"123"` and `"423 234 2359"`, then split each match on one or more spaces. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7mSYc/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

data = '''
alkdj flajf
123 adlf ja;ld fj 999
423 234 2359 kalfji lkja;lkd999
'''
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9 ]+) \w.*?')

pattern.findall(data)
```

Outputs:

```
['123', '423 234 2359']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture numbers separately, we could use the fancy `\G` continue operator:

```
import regex as re
rgx = r"(?|^(\d+)|\G \K(\d+))"
test_str = ("alkdj flajf\n"
    "123 adlf ja;ld fj 999\n"
    "423 234 2359 kalfji lkja;lkd999")

matches = re.finditer(rgx, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLfIFW/1) (the demo requires PCRE, this is why I import the alternative regex module)

I also use a Branch Reset `(?|)` and the `\K` discard operator to make things work.